# How to change the lifetime of a Sentinel remember me cookie?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, session-cookies, sentinel

I have a laravel application which uses Sentinel for authentication. I want to change the lifetime of remember me cookie in Laravel. I want the cookie to expire after 5 days. Anyone experience with Sentinel, please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can make a new cookie with the same name of it and give it the value of it and the time you want it.

use this code and it will work with you.

```
$cookies=\Cookie::get();
$cookies_keys=array_keys(\Cookie::get());
$name='remember_web_';
$remember=collect($cookies_keys)->filter(function ($v) use ($name) {
   return preg_match("/$name/", $v);
});
$remember_me=$cookies[$remember->first()];
\Cookie::make("$remember",\Cookie::get("$remember"),'your_time');
```

Comment: I had thought the same but I was hoping if there is any better way to do this than overriding the cookie itself. Anyway thanks for the help... :)